# Parities of a permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Is there in general any difference between a cyclic and an even permutation? Or can they be used interchangeably. Is an acyclic permutation the same as an odd permutation?

Comment: This is false in both directions. Cyclic does not imply even, and even does not imply cyclic.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there in general any difference between a cyclic and an even permutation?

Yes.

The permutation $(12)(34)$ is even but not cyclic. The permutation $(1234)$ is cyclic but odd.